# Can't change language in Windows

Tags: windows, language

I am trying to change the language on my Windows system. Despite setting every possible language option to English, my Windows still appears German, as you can see in the image below.

[image]

What else is there to change? I really want my Windows in English.

Comment: "setting every possible language option" - if that would be true, then there is no solution to your problem. It would be better to list what you have done, so we can suggest something different.

Comment: As harrymc suggests, please EDIT your question and add the specific things that you have adjusted/changed/tried so that we know what not to suggest and can better get you a good answer.